# Using And instead of branching causes #REF error

Tags: vba

I've written a pretty simple function in VBA, which uses 3 parameters to calculate a certain value with a single expression. The problem is, the function also has to bring up specific message boxes if one of the parameters is not a number or is less or equal to 0.

So for my first try I've come up with this code

```
Function refraction(a, b, c)

If IsNumeric(a) And IsNumeric(b) And IsNumeric(c) Then
    If (a > 0) And (b > 0) And (c > 0) Then
        refraction = (a ^ 2 - 1) * b / c / (a ^ 2 + 2)
    Else
    MsgBox "Range!"
    Exit Function
    End If
Else
MsgBox "Number!"
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Which returns a #REF error whatever the parameters are, even if they are all numeric and positive.

So I tried a more straightforward approach

```
Function refrakcja(a, b, c)

If IsNumeric(a) Then
    If IsNumeric(b) Then
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            If a > 0 Then
                If b > 0 Then
                    If c > 0 Then
                        refrakcja = (a ^ 2 - 1) * b / c / (a ^ 2 + 2)
                    Else
                    MsgBox "Range!"
                    Exit Function
                    End If
                Else
                MsgBox "Range!"
                Exit Function
                End If
            Else
            MsgBox "Range!"
            Exit Function
            End If
        Else
        MsgBox "Number!"
        Exit Function
        End If
    Else
    MsgBox "Number"
    Exit Function
    End If
Else
MsgBox "Number!"
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Which worked like a charm. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Functions should return something for starters. What you have is either a sub and should be written as such or should return ref2 and state a return type in the function signature.

Comment: I am not getting any errors with the first one.  What parameters are you passing?

Comment: @QHarr sorry, I've edited the code a little as I was posting, it should be 'refraction = ' of course. Edited now.

Comment: @ScottCraner literally any set of parameters just isn't working. It's just #REF error, never a correct value, never a message box.

Comment: Again, I cannot get it to do that, no matter what I put.  So please give an example input.

Comment: For "a more straightforward approach", that drifts pretty heavily to the right...

Comment: @ScottCraner literally anything, 10 10 10; 24 -2; 25; hello, precious, world

Comment: If I use `=refraction(10,10,10)` on the worksheet I get `0.970588235` as the answer.  So `HOW are you calling it`

Comment: I've literally just done the same thing and faced #REF again. I'm as clueless as you and see 0 reason for this to be happening.

Comment: should you be using `;` instead of `,` on the worksheet call?

Comment: Of course, that's what I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least you need to `Exit Function` if all numbers and all greater than 0. In example below I am returning a `Variant`. You don't need the other `Exit Functions`. You can let the program run to the end and return what ever value you feel appropriate. You could also consider enforcing type in the function signature and then adding in error handling.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print refraction(12, -4, 3)

End Sub
Public Function refraction(ByVal a As Variant, ByVal b As Variant, ByVal c As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ref2  As Long
    If IsNumeric(a) And IsNumeric(b) And IsNumeric(c) Then
        If (a > 0) And (b > 0) And (c > 0) Then
            ref2 = (a ^ 2 - 1) * b / c / (a ^ 2 + 2)
            refraction = ref2
            Exit Function
        Else
            MsgBox "Range!"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Number!"
    End If
    refraction = "Invalid values passed"
End Function
```

Comment: I've copied your code over, getting rid of the unneeded parts such as byval, debug and such and it worked. As I said before, the "ref2" should have been just "refraction", in accordance with the function name, but I still have no clue why did my variant not work.

Comment: @100ethereals `ByVal` isn't unneeded. Read up on `ByRef` vs `ByVal`, and you'll find that the default (implicit `ByRef`) isn't appropriate 99% of the time.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not planning to go into the depths of VBA programming tbh. This is all a part of my homework, so as to say and I'm pretty confident ByRef is sufficient for things we are doing.

Comment: Until it bites you in the rear end because you didn't bother understanding it. FWIW the concept of passing arguments by value or by reference is just as valid in C# and other languages, understanding it properly in VBA isn't wasted energy. Especially if you're any kind of serious about whatever it is that you're studying that makes you write code.

Comment: "I don't really need to understand it" is a poor attitude for a student, @100ethereals, whether you're paying for the education or your parents are.

Comment: @FreeMan thankfully I'm smart enough to study for free. I study with dedication, but since programming isn't anywhere near my major, I only learn what I've been told to learn on the lectures. My free time is not endless and I'd rather spend it on learning advanced stuff for my major. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the result as the fail value as the first step of the function means you will always return a valid value. Reversing logic to end the function early can make for much more readable code.

```
Function refraction(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, ByVal c As Double) As Variant

    refraction = vbEmpty

    If Not (IsNumeric(a) And IsNumeric(b) And IsNumeric(c)) Then
        MsgBox "A parameter was not numeric"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not ((a > 0) And (b > 0) And (c > 0)) Then
        MsgBox "A parameter was negative"
        Exit Function
    End If

    refraction = (a ^ 2 - 1) * b / c / (a ^ 2 + 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked like a charm, too. But I still have no idea why didn't my variant work :(